# using web service to get a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a zip file and I have client application I need to send my files to web service how I can implement it easily ?

web service should have ability to store them on the server.

Comment: **IS THIS WHAT YOU MEAN???** I have zip-files in my client application, which I need to send to a web service, which will store the zip-files on the server. I need to implement both the client and the server components.

Please, can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it the easy way just by passing an array of bytes to your web service like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318425) or you can use a more complex way and send it as a FileStream (I have never tried the second way) like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/MTOMWebServices.aspx).

Comment: +1 Looks like should OPTION 1: [HOW TO: Send and Receive Binary Documents by Using an ASP.NET Web Service and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318425) should work for small-enough files; even though the code is "a bit sloppy". Why DO Microsoft consistently IGNORE best practices in there code examples? Putzes! Sigh.

Comment: @corlettk:good point :) I guess they just want to show the simplest case to be sure that everyone can understand what's going on but at least they could introduce some more advance references.